# HTML Form element design and implementation

Tags: php, javascript, html

In my case, i would like to let the user select whether some information is publicize, and to what extent is publicize (Read only/ Editable)

So , my idea is:

First ,
public with checkbox, if the checkbox is clicked , then  is editable for everyone

if the checkbox is not clicked, 
then there will be a url link : named eg. select public to...
if that link is clicked , there will be a popup box, every other user is listed  and a selectbox (option:Read ,Edit) for each other users.

Sample:

```
user A  selectbox : Read , Edit
user B  selectbox : Read , Edit
```

The question are:

1)Is this design appropriate?

2)How to 'send' the result from popup box to the form ?

Any help is appreciate . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2)How to 'send' the result from popup box to the form ?

use Jquery dialog: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Then wrap your form that is going to pop-up in div and append it body. What it does is makes your pop-up inside body, so you can then use javascript to perform various actions. For example lets say you have "add-user" button in pop up and field "user" in your form

```
$('#add-user').live('click', function(){
    $("#user").val("User added");
})
```

;

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, what will be the expected result retrieve from popup box? in case there is a  select box with 2 opition 'a & b'